# Install Linux distro with gcc4

Tags: linux, gcc, distribution-choice

How can I find a linux-distro with gcc4-installed?

I've searched internet but without success 
for instance [this wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Linux_distributions)

Comment: Current Debian stable has gcc 4.9 as default.

Answer (score 1):

Version 4 of gcc (Gnu C Compiler) is from 2005, I would guess any semi-recent distribution has that. Whether it's installed by default in any I don't know, but most linux distributions make it easy to install extra software after installation.

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to install all the basic development tools by yourself , the compiler it is not installed by default on a greatest number of Linux distros 
because a lot of users dosn't need to compile anything..

Example 1: To set your devloppement environnement on based Debian distributions , you need to install `build-essential` .

Example 2 : On [RED HAT ENTERPRISE LINUX](http://developers.redhat.com/products/rhel/get-started/) you need to install Red Hat Developer Toolset which contains a suite of development tools including `gcc`